# Display(Graphs & DataGridViews) Slow to Update

Tags: .net, vb.net, graph, datagridview, display

I have a program (made with .net using visualstudio 2012 desktop) that needs to update a few datagridviews and graphs with new data every second. The issue i am having is that the form pauses for a long time (approx 1-2sec) while these datagridviews are being updated. There are 7 datagridviews and 2 graphs.

The datagridviews are updated by looping through each row and then updating the cells individually. The display is then updated with a "datagridview.update()" for each datagridview.

The graphs have new points added as required and then are also updated using graph.update().

I have done some research and added a few things like making the column widths fixed. But running the script does not seem to be what is taking the time.

I have run a profiler over the program which showed that most of the time (approx 90%) is spent in the OnPaint method which is called every time i call datagridview.update() or graph.update()

Does anyone have any advice on how i can make this more effecient but still updating the form at the same rate. Most of the googling ablout On.paint is about drawing lines and points

Updated 22/02/2017
Here's my attempt at summarizing it for one of the datagridviews. Thanks in advance sorry for being a noob.

`Public Class Session
    Public DataGroups(999) As DataGroup
End Class

Public Class DataGroup
    Dim CurrentLineRow as integer
    Dim Value1 as Double
    Dim Value2 as Double
    Dim Value3 as Double
    Dim Value4 as Double
    'etc...
End Class

Public Class Form1

Public CurrentSession As New Session

'The following data is updated as it is read from a text file elsewhere in the program
CurrentSession.DataGroups(Index1FromTextFile).CurrentLineRow  = LineRowValueFromTextFile
CurrentSession.DataGroups(Index1FromTextFile).Value1 = Value1FromTextFile
CurrentSession.DataGroups(Index1FromTextFile).Value2 = Value2FromTextFile
etc....
CurrentSession.DataGroups(Index2FromTextFile).CurrentLineRow  = LineRowValueFromTextFile2
CurrentSession.DataGroups(Index2FromTextFile).Value1 = Value1FromTextFile2
CurrentSession.DataGroups(Index2FromTextFile).Value2 = Value2FromTextFile2
etc.. etc..

Private Sub CellValueChanged()

    For r As Integer = 1 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1 'loop through rows

                    'Sets Default Colours and Styles. These need to be reset as they can get changed later in the sub
t                    For c As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
                        'Set Cell to default colour
                        DataGridView1(c, r).Style.BackColor = Color.Black
                        DataGridView1(c, r).Style.ForeColor = Color.White
                        DataGridView1(c, r).Style.Font = New Font("Verdana", 12, FontStyle.Regular)
                    Next


                    'Get DataGroup that matches row
                    Dim RowDataGroup As DataGroup = Nothing
                    For i As Integer = 1 To CurrentSession.DataGroups.Length - 1
                        If CurrentSession.DataGroups(i) IsNot Nothing Then
                            If CurrentSession.DataGroups(i).CurrentLineRow = r Then
                                RowDataGroup = CurrentSession.DataGroups(i)
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next

                    If RowDataGroup IsNot Nothing Then 'Skip code if DataGroup could not be found

                          'Similar code to this is repeated for each column (total of 40 columns)      
                          If RowDataGroup.Value 1 Then
                                DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells("Column1").Value = Math.Round(owDataGroup.Value1, 2)
                                DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells("Column1").Style.ForeColor = Color.Green
                          End If

                   End If

    Next

    DataGridView1.Update() 'Acording to the profiller this is what is taking the majority of the time

End Sub

End Class`

Comment: Please read [Ask] and take the [tour].  No one can can with certainty why your code runs slowly without seeing the code that runs slowly.  But my crystal ball says `looping through each row` is part of it and `a "datagridview.update()"`. may also be involved.

Comment: My crystal ball says the same as Plutonix's. But it has also hinted that  the normal way to approach this would be to populate a dataset or list of objects from your data, and then use that as a datasource for the grid, binding it via a BindingSource.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did read the how to post guide but I did't put any code up as the program is very large. This is why i ran the performance profiler. I've updated the post with a sumarized version